# Return a constant set of key value pair

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

Imagine I have something like the following

```
SELECT 0 AS 'Key','No' AS 'Value'
UNION
SELECT 1 AS 'Key','YES' AS 'Value'
UNION  
SELECT 2 AS 'Key','Maybe' AS 'Value'
....
....
```

How can I make above statement more readable so I can accommodate more constant key/value pair in above list in a single select statement? I don't want to create table variable or create a complex sql statement. Just a single select statement returning bunch of constant key/pair values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `VALUES`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES 
    (0, 'No'),
    (1, 'Yes'),
    (2, 'Maybe')
) t([Key], Value)
```

[Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql)

Answer (score 2):

Using a table value constructor.

```
VALUES ((0,'NO'),(1,'YES'),(2,'MAYBE'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Understand you don't want to create a table variable
I use the accepted answer a lot +1
Just pointing out a table variable lets you declare type and primary key

```
declare @tbl table ([key] tinyint primary key,  [value] varchar(12));
insert into @tbl values (1, 'one')
                      , (2, 'two')
                      , (3, 'three');
select * from @tbl order by [key];
```

Comment: I certainly will take a note of that. Your effort is appreciate!